# Apache SSL - self signed certificate

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

I know this might be a very newbee question, but I couldn't find anywhere how to solve this.

I managed to create a self signed certificate for my production environment (apache) and activated SSL, but when accessing my server through HTTPS, the browser says the "connection is untrusted".

Do I really need to pay for companies like Tawte or Verisign do get rid of that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hope this is internal-only: self-signed certificates shouldn't be used in production.

Comment: If this is a public-facing server then look at https://letsencrypt.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes.  Browsers trust the Certificate Authorities that sign and deliver your certificates.  This is what you're paying for when you purchase an SSL certificate from Verisign, Thawte, etc.

Having said that, if this is internal, you can certainly install your certificate/chain on the client-side so that your self-signed certificate is trusted, but with GoDaddy selling domain-verified certificates for ~$40-50 annually (cheaper with coupons, longer-term, etc.), why bother?

Comment: Also, level 1 certificates from StartSSL are available at no cost. If this is a public-facing server, then there's a reasonable expectation that your TLS certificate will be signed by a recognized certifying authority. Self-signed certificates are only reasonable for internal use, testing, or for limited external use.

Answer (score 0):

The warning displayed by the browser is due to the certificate is self signed. You can add an eception to this in your browser, and it will function like Ordinary in your browser hereafter.

If you need your certificatte issued by an ssl provider, please contact them for the same